# Python парсер выдаёт None

Tags: python, парсер

В общем пытаюсь получить хоть какие теги с этого сайта, и всегда выдает none. Не имею понятия как это исправить, гуглил, ничего не смог найти. P.S только начал изучать это.

```
# coding: utf-8-sig
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}

def get_html(url):

    request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    table = soup.find('body', class_='panel-open')
    print(table)

def  main():
    parse(get_html('http://toto-info.co/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()# coding: utf-8-sig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По данному адресу на странице и нет ни одного элемента с классом panel-open.

Вообще, похоже, что значительная часть контента на странице конструируется скриптами в какой-то момент уже после её загрузки. Не уверен, что чистый BeautifulSoup сможет с этим справится. Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону Selenium.

Comment: Это вроде раскрывающегося списка там, типо того что жмёшь на вкладку, и появляется панель, которую надо распарсить, но не имею понятия как.